# regular expression to allow only numbers in range 1-20

Tags: regex

I want to make user to enter numbers in 0-20 range and they can both enter 01 and 1

this is what I have so far

```
 /^[1-9]|0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0]$/
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is that `|` has lower precedence than `^` and `$`, so your pattern means `^[1-9]` *or* `0[1-9]` *or* `1[0-9]` *or* `2[0]$`: only single-digit values are restricted by `^`, and only `20` is restricted by `$`.

You can either repeat `^` and `$` in each branch of the alternation, or else wrap the alternation in `(?:...)` to create a non-capturing subexpression:

```
/^[1-9]$|^0[1-9]$|^1[0-9]$|^20$/
/^(?:[1-9]|0[1-9]|1[0-9]|20)$/
```

(I've also taken the liberty of changing `[0]` to `0`.)

Comment: @ruakh I want to have decimals up to 2 places in the expression... How do I do it? So far I came up with `/^(?:[1-9]+.+[0-9]{2}|0[1-9]+.+[0-9]{2}|1[0-9]+.+[0-9]{2}|20)$/`. Is this correct?

Comment: @Yufenyuy: No, that doesn't make sense. (`.+` doesn't mean what you seem to want it to.) I suggest you ask a separate question.

Comment: @ruakh what does `.+` mean then... I went further to modify the above to: `/^(?:[0-9]|0[1-9]|1[0-9]|[0-9]+.+[0-9]{1,2}|0[1-9]+.+[0-9]{1,2}|1[0-9]+.+[0-9]{1,2}|20)$/`. It seems to work except that it takes decimals above 20. (ex. `20.05`).

Answer (score 9):

How about

```
/^([0-1]?[0-9]|20)$/
```

The problem is that 20 is a special case. The second section covers it. The first section covers the rest. I'm assuming perl-style regular expressions, since you didn't specify the context.

Comment: Could you tell me what's wrong with my code? I just learnt the regex by myself this morning.

Comment: As ruakh specified in his answer, it's a priority thing - you'll need to parenthesize the block in order to make sure the '^' and '$' sign have a lower priority than the rest of the expression.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `[1]?[0-9]|20`? Other wise you might match stuff like `01`.

Comment: Note that the OP is looking to match numbers 1–20, but the regex in this answer also matches zero (`0` or `00`). But a *bit* of condensing is possible, at least, by using `0?[1-9]` to cover 1–9 with or without a leading zero.

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
/^([01]?\d|20)$/
```

0 or 1 (optional) followed by at least one digit OR 20

Comment: This will allow 00. Should that be prohibited?

Comment: If 00 is not allowed /^(0[1-9]|1\d|20)$/

Comment: No, if 00 is not allowed it's /^([1-9]|1\d|20)$/