# PHP Regex for font-size limit

Tags: php, regex

I'm having some trouble with Regex never really used it. However basically I'm trying to set a limit on my font-size bbcode tag.

```
class SizeValidator implements \JBBCode\InputValidator
{

public function validate($input)
{
    return (bool) preg_match('regex', $input);
}

}
```

If someone can help with the regex that'll be perfect! Basically just want Size 7 to 30 max, no px, em, nothing strictly numbers max 2 numbers if anyone with regex experience would be quite helpful possibly explain how it works so I can improve and get a better understanding :)

Comment: Could you give some examples of valid & invalid inputs, please?

Comment: check this it will help to you 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12183223/regular-expression-to-allow-only-numbers-in-range-1-20

Comment: Well, for this size bbcode I haven't done the regex due to lack of experience however perhaps this could be of use; http://pastebin.com/cgpzVvbM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really is no reason to use regular expressions here.

Simply verify that what you're getting is a sequence of digits (for instance using [`ctype_digit`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php), and that the value lies between 7 and 30.

```
class SizeValidator implements \JBBCode\InputValidator {
    public function validate($input) {
        return ctype_digit($input) && $input >= 7 && $input <= 30;
    }
}
```

It's much more readable and easier to modify if need be.

Comment: Um, indeed let me give it a run and let's see.

Comment: Well it failed and that's probably cause the regex doesn't define the tag aswell; [size=option]param[/size] or well my mistake I should say it requires regex to define the tag.

Comment: @user3354480: That really shouldn't be necessary in jBBCode. Just define your tag [like this](https://gist.github.com/Eckankar/3ef83d00ea4af2210de6).

Comment: Thanks my friend, appreciate the help.

Answer (score -1):

You could try something like this:

```
return (bool)preg_match('/\[size=(([7-9])|([1-2]\d)|(30))\](.*)?\[\/size\]/', $input);
```

First I am matching if the number is 7-9, if so your function returns true.

```
([7-9])
```

Else if your number is with two digits starting with either 1 or 2 then the function also returns true

```
([1-2]\d)
```

Or else I check if the number is 30 and return true.

Comment: Well it failed and that's probably cause the regex doesn't define the tag aswell; [size=option]param[/size]

Comment: Testing the code alone like this; http://pastebin.com/NZ5nr0h2 works perfectly fine tho.

Comment: @user3354480 ok I'll add also the tag.